# Tableau - how to change data source by using a script (programmatically)

Tags: bash, automation, tableau-api

I am working on a task where there are 100 of Tableau reports. What is the best approach to change .twb files to point data source from one database to another?
Can this be done programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean different instances of the same database platform (ie a different server) or to a completely different platform (is MySql to Oracle)?

Comment: Different platform...

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that. I'm not going to say it can't be done. I'm going to say that after 5 years, I haven't figured out how to easily do it without hacking the twb files individually or using the Replace Data Source in each file individually. I will be watching to see if someone else has a suggestion.

Comment: Are you using any published data sources for your reports? If not, could those 100 reports be switched to published data sources in a way that you would only need a few published data sources for all of the reports?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @SamM Yes there are published data sources for reports.

Comment: If 100 workbooks connect to a single published data source, then you need only change the published data source to have all the workbooks now see the data coming from the new source. Changing that source to a new type could be a bit of a hassle, requiring copying calculated fields, temporary blends to pull in aliases and groups etc, but then just publish with the same name.

Comment: Where would you change a data source in .twb file? File looks like having 30K lines.. Was thinking if could script changing data source there..